# Converting Binary String into byte and not char while writing to file

Tags: java, java-io

I want to write the file as byte only and not the character.

```
String binaryString = "10110101"
```

I am using

```
byte mybyte  = Byte.parseByte(binaryString,2);
```

I want to write this converted byte into the file as a `byte` and not the character.

I am using :

```
FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(new File("output"));
fos.write(mybyte);
```

But after write, when I see the files the byte is actually written as the characters.

Is I am doing something wrong in conversion ? How to make it write as **byte and not char** ?

Edit:

Like for the String **101101010111001011111000** (taking 8 bits at a time and then writing to the file) : it is converted to "Z9|".

Comment: "But after write, when I see the files the byte is actually written as the characters." - how are you "seeing" that? A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would help.

Comment: (In fact, `Byte.parseByte` will throw an exception for that input...)

Comment: @ Jon Skeet This is the problem that when I open the file with such byte written they are just appearing as a Character so I can see them

Comment: You "open" it with a _text_ editor?

Comment: @Njol In such cases, the data is not actually readable due to raw bytes but for me it's properly readable.

Comment: `(10110101)2 = (181)10` byte range is `[-128, 127]`

Comment: I am opening it in gedit

Comment: What do you think gedit does? It will interpret it like - well I guess ASCII?

Comment: Use a hexadecimal editor, or a terminal hexadecimal viewer like `xxd`

Comment: @h3nr1x I have also tried the terminal window in ubuntu, there is same problem. It is acutally converted into proper character

Comment: How did you "try the terminal window"? Like "less" or something? You _really_ need a tool that displays HEX.

Comment: @Gaurav Can you edit your question and just type an example of what you expect to see when you open that file in an editor?

Comment: Please provide the output of `od -xc output` assuming you wrote to `output`

Answer (score 1):

You actually write the binary data 10110101 to the file, but when you open that file in a text editor it will be displayed as a character.

If you want to write *text that represent the given number* (e.g. in decimal form), use a Writer:

```
FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(new File("output"));
OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(fos1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
w.write(""+mybyte); // ""+mybyte creates a string with the decimal representation of mybyte
```

Comment: The Decimal representation will be converted into the character and we loose the actual byte.

Comment: @Gaurav this code e.g. writes the characters `105` (3 bytes) to the file instead of writing a byte like your code does. If you want an actual byte then your code is already correct (ignoring the signed bytes issue), you just have to open the file in a hex editor or similar.

Comment: I don't want all the bytes at same time, I want the data represented byte by byte in the file